# R zeroinfl model error - what does this mean?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a simple poisson model of zero inflated with zeroinfl library. Getting a strange error anyway I try it. Any thoughts?

```
mdl2 <- mtcars %>% zeroinfl(formula = "mpg ~ cyl")
Error in formula[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
mdl2 <- mtcars %>% zeroinfl(formula = "mpg ~ cyl | cyl")
Error in formula[[3]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the quotes, you are giving a character string and not a formula.

```
> class("mpg ~ cyl")
[1] "character"
> class(mpg ~ cyl)
[1] "formula"
> mtcars %>% pscl::zeroinfl(formula = vs ~ cyl)
# works
```

If you need to build a formula from a set of strings, you can call `as.formula("vs ~ cyl")`.